# ERROR TOO MANY REDIRECT!

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola a todos una vez más preguntando aquí ya que no he podido dar solucion a este problema.
Estoy trabajando en la paginación de un sistema de reseñas, todo va muy bien excepto cuando pongo las condiciones de redirección en caso de que el usuario quiera saltar la paginación a un número desconocido.
Me explico mejor, la paginación añade a la url base el prefijo index.php?page_reviews=1 y aumenta o disminuye dependiendo la cantidad de reseñas que hayan. ahora si en la paginación solo existen 3 páginas el usuario podrá acceder a index.php?page_reviews=3, que pasa si pone el 4 en vez del 3, le muestra una página que no existe lo mismo si se va a 0 o números negativos, para solucionar hice dos redireccionamientos: El primero añade por defecto el index.php?page_reviews=1 por defecto y el segundo evita que el usuario vaya a páginas que no existen.

Ahora el problema es que si pongo esto en el heaader, me causa el error TOO MAY REDIRECTS, y si lo pongo en el body me da el error Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by.

```php
 if(!$_GET){
    header('location:index.php?page_reviews=1');
}
if($_GET['page_reviews']>$paginas) || $_GET['page_reviews']<=0 ){
    header('location:index.php?page_reviews=1');
}
```

EL SQL que uso es este

```SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM avatrade WHERE lang='$lang' ORDER BY review_id DESC";
$sentencia =$pdo-> prepare($sql);
$sentencia-> execute();

$resultado = $sentencia ->fetchAll();

$comentarios_x_pagina= 10;

$comentarios_totales = $sentencia->rowcount();
$paginas = $comentarios_totales /$comentarios_x_pagina;
$paginas = ceil($paginas);
$iniciar=($_GET['page_reviews']-1)*$comentarios_x_pagina;
```

Yo sé que el problema es causado por el loop de las redirecciones: Este probelam solo se presenta cuando la base de datos está vacia, ya que calcula el # de resñas y el # de paginas a crear.

Si alguien me puede indicar como solucionar esto le agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es asegurarse de que `$paginas` sea mayor igual a `1`.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$paginas = max(ceil($paginas), 1);
```

---

**Referencias**:

- [PHP: max()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php)

Comment: Pero cuando escribo index.php?page_reviews=0 o en negativo se cae el sitio

Comment: @RobinRamirez, agrega un `die();` después de la llamada a `header`